# How to create a non-linear sequence of numbers given only the starting and ending and number of steps

Tags: scala, math, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I am working on tuning a logistic regression model in Apache Spark using cross validation.

I would like to create a range of numbers that follow an exponential curve, e.g. each element in the list is obtained by multiplying the number before it by some constant, C.  I will use this range as the regularization options in the paramGrid.

The trick is, I want to do this iteratively, so that the parameters of the best model is used to narrow down the window for the search range.  Therefore, after the first iteration, I need a way to programmatically calculate C given X, Y, and N.

If there is a function I can use which will give me what I want, great.  Otherwise, what is the formula for calculating C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want that

```
Y = X*C^N
```

which means that you compute the factor as

```
C = pow(Y/X, 1.0/N)
```

Comment: Thank you!  That works, except for one minor change: If I'm going to have N numbers, that means I'm going to have N-1 transitions, so it is 1.0/(N-1) and N goes from 0 to N-1 when generating the samples.